# Counting the Number of TH's in each Table using XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Stuck in a rabbit hole trying to parse an HTML file.

The basics:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('myfile.html');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

After this initialization, my technique has been to use XPATH queries to get the variables I want.

I've had no issue, really, if there is one specific item, or node-- very easy to pinpoint and retrieve.

So within my loaded HTML, it's formed basically in a loop. Minified it looks like this:

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="desc-wrap">
        Text Text Text
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrap">
        <table class="table-wrap">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="range">Range </th>
                    <th>#1</th>
                    <th>#2</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="intro">
    <div class="desc-wrap">
        Text Text Text
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrap">
        <table class="table-wrap">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="range">Range </th>
                    <th>#1</th>
                    <th>#2</th>
                    <th>#3</th>
                    <th>#4</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This continues on 100 times (meaning 100 instances of `<div class="intro"> . . . </div>`

So I'm trying to get the contents of `desc-wrap` (no problem there), and the text nodes as well as a count of how many `<th>`'s are in each table.

Thinking perhaps one XPath query might be better than two, I query the div.

```
$intropath = $xp->query("//div[@class='intro']");
```

Loop it.

```
$f=1;
foreach ($intropath as $sp) {
echo $f++ . '<br />'; // Makes it way to 100, good.
```

My question / core issue I'm having is trying to count the number of `<th>`'s in each table.

```
$gettables = $xp->query("//div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]//th", $sp);
var_dump($getsizes); // public 'length' => int 488
// Okay, so this is getting all the <th> elements in the 
// entire document, not just in the loop. Maybe not what I want.
```

Here's what else I've tried (failed at, I mean)

Well, let's try just to target the first table (adding `[0]` before `//th`), see if we can get something.

```
$gettables = $xp->query("//div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')][0]//th", $sp);
```

Nope. Non-Object. Length 0. Not sure why. Okay, let's take that off.

Maybe try this?

```
//div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]//th[count(following-sibling::*)]
```

Okay. So Length = 100. Must be getting a single `th` and extrapolating. Not what I want.

Maybe just

```
//th[count(*)]
```

Nope. Non-object.

Maybe this?

```
count(//div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]//th)
```

Nope. More Non-Objects.

That's probably enough examples of what I've tried.
It's been fun failing (and okay, learning), but what am I missing?
My output... I just want to find out how many `<th>`'s are in each table.

So, like:

```
foreach ($intropath as $sp) {
$xpath = $xp->query("//actual/working/xpath/for/individual/th");
$thcount = count($getsizes->item(0)); // or something?
echo $thcount . '<br>';
```

In the example above, would output

> 3
>
> 5

and of course continue for the other 98 iterations..

This is probably stupid easy. I've been referencing this [cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14) and also this [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) and I've learned a lot about XPATH's capabilities, but this answer is alluding me. At this point I'm not even sure if doing my `foreach ($intropath as $sp) {` was even the proper way to achieve what I'm doing.

Anyone feel like digging me out of this hole so I can move on with the next step and/or my life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the qualifying nodes using iterated `query()` calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3uuK9))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query("//div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]//tr") as $node) {
    echo $xp->query("th", $node)->length , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
3
5
```

Comment: Yes! Finally. :) This is working thank you.  Looking into it more still.  May I ask if I need to do this within its own `foreach` loop as illustrated in your answer, or can I (or should I?) do it within my original `foreach` loop with the div?

Comment: You can extend the first query like this: `//div[@class='intro']/div[contains(@class,'main-wrap')]/table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]//tr` if that's what you are asking.  You don't need three nested loops.  Demo: https://3v4l.org/79WXu

Comment: (so you know I upvoted your question already)  Thanks for the upvote/acceptance. CRACKED 20K!  Now I'm happy/sad -- I thought that was the final milestone -- it's not.  The addiction/pursuit continues.

Comment: Nah, you got it my friend.  I'm just messing with the detritus of it all. And does it ever end? I hope so. Glad I could help push you over. And sorry to hear it didn't transform you into an enlightened coding God as many guru's have said in the past. Maybe 40K? :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out when it ends and I'm getting hung up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a

Comment: It seems I have one more to go.  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2017/12/09/stack-overflow-milestone/\

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah but you know when you get that one you're just going to keep wondering about 200k...

Comment: @mickmackusa no... I've always (probably stupidly) been a "build it from the ground up" sort of programmer.

Comment: Perhaps the human brain is never satisfied; Always looking for what is next.  Be advised though, the rabbit hole is not what it appears. It's paradoxical and conniving, it twists and turns. You may think you've found your way out only to realize you've only just begun.

Answer (score 0):

At first, query the `table`s:

```
$intropath = $xp->xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]");
```

Then get the count of `th`s for each `table` with another XPath query and the `count` PHP function applied to all `th`s relative to the context node:

```
foreach ($intropath as $tab) {
  $count = count($tab->xpath(".//th"));
  echo $count . "<br>";
}
```

This should be all.

**P.S.:**
Apparently PHP doesn't like the XPath `count` function, so I used the PHP `count` function instead.

---

Just for completeness:
If you can use XPath-2.0, the following expression will be more compact:

```
string-join(//table[contains(@class, 'table-wrap')]/count(.//th),'#')
```

Here, `#` is the delimiter between each `table`s count.

Comment: You can do another `query` on the `foreach` queries key? Wasn't aware. Either way, It's not working.. doing a `var_dump` on `$intropath` brings back a length of `240`... doing a `var_dump` on `$tab` brings in the `th` content in `textContent`... but I'm seeing no outlet to count the number of `th`'s.  Anyways, doing the code as is I'm just getting `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::query()` for the `$count` line..

Comment: OK. I haven't tested it. Sorry for that. I changed the answer to another `->xpath` query.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate any possible help.  No idea why it's not working though.  First one, I changed... now I'm just getting `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::xpath()` ... second one.... looks cool, still testing though :) (honestly XPath-2.0, I don't know about :P - or if I have it, or if it needs to be in a loop or on its own.  Right now I'm just getting `false` for everything so..

Comment: Is `->xpath` only for XML files? Not sure. I think that may be the issue, I'm trying to parse HTML/DOM.. Adding to `$intropath` reveals the same error.  Confusing... umm.. I'm on PHP 7.1.16... do I need an extension? Trying to figure this out :P

Comment: I changed the `count` function from XPath to PHP and now it works as desired. I tested it with [http://phptester.net/](http://phptester.net/) PHP version 7.0.

Comment: Right.. I mean if I just use `count($thquery)` on a `//th` `query` it brings back `1111111111111111`.. so I mean that's something.  Honestly I'm baffled as to why I can't use `xpath` though, anywhere it seems.  If you tested it, it's probably just me, but whenever and wherever I try to use it I'm getting `Call to undefined method DOMXPath::xpath()`.. I'll have to look into more as to why.

Comment: That may be the problem. I used `SimpleXML` for testing. However, I'm glad that the other answer does work for you.